# java streams: grouping by and add fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I've a stream of `MetricGroup`, where:

```
public class MetricGroup {

    private String application;
    private int uploadedDocs;
    private long uploadedKbs;

    // getters and setters

}
```

I need to sumarize all application metrics. I mean, for each application (`MetricGroup.application`) I need to add all `metric.uploadedDocs` into a `sumMetric.uploadedDocs` and `metric.uploadedKds` into a `sumMetric.uploadedKbs`.

I figure out I need some kind of `groupingBy`

```
Stream.of(
    new MetricGroup("app1", 1,100),
    new MetricGroup("app1", 1,300),
    new MetricGroup("app2", 1,200)
)
.collect(Collector.groupingBy(MetricGroup::getApplication, accumulator??, combiner??)
```

The result would be a stream with:

```
< MetricGroup("app1", 2, 400) , MetricGroup("app2", 1, 200) >
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with the answers you got on your [similar question asked 30 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089939/java-streams-straightforward-reduce)?

Comment: I need to group by application, On the other post only I need to summarize all objects. Now I need to summarize by application.

Answer (score 4):

You can group by `application` and then map the results to `MetricGroup`:

```
source.stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(MetricGroup::getApplication))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .map(s -> new MetricGroup(s.getKey(), 
                 s.getValue().stream().mapToInt(MetricGroup::getUploadedDocs).sum(),
                 s.getValue().stream().mapToLong(MetricGroup::getUploadedKbs).sum()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you could add the following copy constructor and `merge` method to the `MetricGroup` class:

```
public MetricGroup(MetricGroup another) {
    this.application = another.application;
    this.uploadedDocs = another.uploadedDocs;
    this.uploadedKbs = another.uploadedKbs;
}

public MetricGroup merge(MetricGroup another) {
    this.uploadedDocs += another.uploadedDocs;
    this.uploadedKbs += another.uploadedKbs;
    return this;
}
```

Then, you could use `Collectors.toMap` to group metrics by application:

```
Map<String, MetricGroup> result = Stream.of(
        new MetricGroup("app1", 1,100), 
        new MetricGroup("app1", 1,300), 
        new MetricGroup("app2", 1,200))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
        MetricGroup::getApplication, 
        MetricGroup::new,      // use copy constructor
        MetricGroup::merge));  // use MetricGroup.merge method
```

Note that we need to use the copy constructor to not mutate the original `MetricGroup` elements of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
private static final List<MetricGroup> mgArr = Arrays.asList(new MetricGroup("app1", 1,100),new MetricGroup("app1", 1,300),new MetricGroup("app2", 1,200));

Map<String, Long> groupedByAppKbs = mgArr.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(MetricGroup::getApplication, summingLong(MetricGroup::getUploadedKbs)));
```

Than to access the vaues:

```
groupedByAppKbs.get("app1").longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collectors.reducing` while grouping by `MetricGroup.application`:

```
Map<String, MetricGroup> collect = 
      source.stream()
            .collect(
                   groupingBy(MetricGroup::getApplication,
                              reducing(new MetricGroup(null, 0, 0),
                                       (m1, m2) -> new MetricGroup(
                                               m2.application,
                                               m1.getUploadedDocs() + m2.getUploadedDocs(),
                                               m1.getUploadedKbs() + m2.getUploadedKbs()))));
```